# Why does this custom comparator fail in construcing std::priority_queue while it works for std::sort?

Tags: c++

A comparator `comp` was defined as below. It works fine with `std::sort`, but fails to compile in the constructor of `std::priority_queue`. What is the problem? Thanks.

```
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool comp(int a, int b) { return a > b; }

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec = {4, 2, 1, 3};
    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), comp); // OK
    priority_queue<int> q1(less<int>(), vec); // OK
    priority_queue<int> q2(comp, vec); // Fail
    return 0;
}
```

Error message:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::priority_queue<int>::priority_queue(bool (&)(int, int), std::vector<int>&)'
  priority_queue<int> q2(comp, vec);
                                  ^
```

Comment: because the [default template parameter of `Compare`](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) is `std::less` you'll require a different template instantiation, while in the `sort` call the comparator type is deduced automatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of the default comparator of `std::priority_queue` is `std::less<T>` where `T` is the value type. You are passing something of type `bool(*)(int, int)` instead. `std::sort()` being a function can deduce the comparator's type. Class types can't deduce their template arguments (yet - there us discussion in the C++ committee that a future version may have class templates whose template arguments can be deduced.

You can use

```
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, bool(*)(int, int)> q(comp);
```

or, avoiding a hard-to-inline function pointer:

```
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int> > q;
```

Comment: Sorry for my very naive question - how `bool(*)(int, int)`?  Isn't the return type of `comp()` just `bool`?

Comment: The entity doing the comparison is an object. The default object is `std::less<int>()`. An object of the comparison object is stored with the priority queue (or passed to `std::sort()`). When storing a function the result (`bool`) is insufficient and an object representing the function to be called is needed. For a function with the signature `bool(int, int)` you'd use a pointer, i.e., `bool(*)(int, int)`.